# mysql unduplicate by appending value to only 1 of the 2 duplicate column results

Tags: mysql, duplicates, unique

I have situation in mysql where in 1 table 1 column did not have a unique constraint on it and should have. Now have rows that have duplicate values but record in entirety is not a duplicate - i.e. do not want to delete. I need to update column with duplicates by appending a value to end of only one of the duplicates so it becomes now unique. Thousands of these exist.
Example table:

```
ColA          ColB
H1000         99872
H1000         643480
B2100         72435
B2100         043856
```

Need:

```
ColA          ColB
H1000         99872
H1000a        643480
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @var :='';
    UPDATE table
    SET cola= (@var :=CASE WHEN cola = @var THEN CONCAT(@var,'a') ELSE cola END)
    ORDER BY cola ASC,colb DESC
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dba7/1)

Comment: Use `ORDER BY ColA` in `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Also, just initialize `@var` to empty string. `SELECT @var := ColA FROM table` evaluates all rows and sets `@var` to the last ColA value.

Comment: Nice solution. One final comment is you may have to run this more than once if you have values that repeat more than once. In that case, you may end up with values like `H1000`, `H1000a`, `H1000aa`, etc.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Yeah i thought about it but I coudnt find a single solution for triplicates and above,you have to run it again this time with CONCAT(..,b) and so on.An easy way out is that he said duplicates...

Comment: Awesome solution and I do only have dups, no triples. Worked like a charm. I don't understand how its working though, what is := doing?

Comment: @user2433754 var is a user  variable and it remebers the previous value,so it updates col a with var and here is another condition if cola=var then add an extra a;at first the val is empty so the ELSE cola condition triggers filling var with cola,then at the second row var is cola from the previous row so it triggers the first condition THEN CONCAT(@var,'a')

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the table structure you should be able to add a new column which I would make an auto incrementing integer column you should be able to use this column to uniquely reference all rows.

You can then use a query like this to identify the duplicates :

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count 
     FROM tablename 
     GROUP BY ColA, ColB 
     HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: To find the duplicates in ColA only, I think you will need to group by just ColA.

Answer (score 0):

Write an update statement
;
`UPDATE tablename`
`SET ColA = 'H1000a'`
`where ColA = 'H1000' and ColB = '643480'`

add a unique index or primary key on Column A to prevent this in the future.

Dan

Comment: OP said that there were 1000's of these rows.  I'm thinking they want something a bit more dynamic than writing 1000's of updates.